# Allow a function to work only in a specific region

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a function that places a cube on a gridhelper, but I want to prevent the user from placing block outside of the region covered by the gridhelper. Here's what I tried:

```
const regionBox = new THREE.Box3(
  new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
  new THREE.Vector3(LENGTH_OF_CANVAS, LENGTH_OF_CANVAS, LENGTH_OF_CANVAS)
);

// Get the object's bounding box
const objectBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(intersect.object);

// Check if the object's bounding box intersects with the region's bounding box
const isInside = objectBox.intersectsBox(regionBox);

if (isInside) {
  console.log("inside");
} else {
  console.log("outside");
}
```

What's the problem? Sometimes it works, sometimes it's not. You can place a cube by clicking on the gridhelper, or by clicking on another cube. A cube's width and height is 50 units, and when you click on the grid helper, the cube's position given by the variable "intersect.object" is under 0 (it is always like 0.50000001) so it's technically outside the region even though it is placed or visually inside.

I know it's kind of a vague explanation, but I used a threejs example as a base code, which provide the cube placing function so you have better and wider context to understand I guess...
Here's the example: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=ve#webgl_interactive_voxelpainter
Here's the code: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_interactive_voxelpainter.html